# How to sync the time between my application and the server?

Tags: java, android, random

The code below generates 7 random digits every 30secs.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Timer timeoutTimer;
final Random myRandom = new Random();
GenerateTask genTask = new GenerateTask();
static String RAN_TEXT = "text";

class GenerateTask extends TimerTask {
    boolean started = false;
    public void run() {
        if (started) {
            System.out.println("generating");
            final TextView textGenerateNumber = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.generatenumber);



           RAN_TEXT = "";

            for(int k=0;k<7;k++){
                RAN_TEXT += myRandom.nextInt(10) + " ";
            }
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    textGenerateNumber.setText(RAN_TEXT);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




     Button buttonGenerate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.generateme);


    buttonGenerate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             System.out.println("click");
             if (!genTask.started) {
                 genTask.started=true;
                 timeoutTimer = new Timer();
                 timeoutTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(genTask, 0, 30000);
             } else {
                 genTask.started=false;
                 timeoutTimer.cancel();
             }
         }
     });  
 }
}
```

I will sync the application time to the server:

```
http://server10.instaforex.com:2012/TimeService/TimeService.svc?wsdl
```

How do I sync the server time to my application?

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to use Http connection

See below code

```
public long getCurrentTimeFromServer() {

    long serverTime = 0;
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(
            "your url");
    HttpResponse response;
    try {
        response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        // Examine the response status
        // Get hold of the response entity
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        // If the response does not enclose an entity, there is no need
        // to worry about connection release

        if (entity != null) {

            // A Simple JSON Response Read
            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
            String result = Utilities.convertinputStreamToString(instream);
            serverTime = Long.parseLong(result);
            // now you have the string representation of the HTML request
            instream.close();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("tag", "error", e);
    }

    return serverTime;
}
```

Comment: do i need to create another java class for that code? and for the URL do i just paste this (http://server10.instaforex.com:2012/TimeService/TimeService.svc?wsdl) right?

Comment: I think you will need to create webservice type which ill return server time

Comment: hmm ok, but i dont know how to do that? and what about the code above?

Answer (score 0):

In order to acheave your goal, you need first to get the right time from your server. I sow that on the server side, you have wsdl, so on your client side (your app), you need to create a process which will connect to the server and get the time.

On how to do that, check here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-android/index.html

After that, you will have the right time locally in you app and you will be able to do whatever with that time.